# make dependencies: skip vendor and package headers with gcc?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, gnu-make, dependency-management, gcc6

I'm starting a new project and thinking of using gcc 6.3.1 `-MM` to generate the dependencies into a file called `Make.Dep`, that I'll include from `Makefile`.

The `-M` option outputs *all* headers, including system headers.  The `-MM` option doesn't output system headers, but I'm still buried in literally thousands of vendor and package headers such as Sybase and Boost, which I don't think will change (and if they do I'm happy to have to do a full rebuild manually).

Obviously I could wrap gcc -MM in a perl script or what have you that knows what directories I consider packages, but is there some more widely-accepted solution?

Note that one of my vendors' headers look for specific gcc-defined pre-processor symbols to configure their portability.  I'd rather not curate a set of such symbols manually to allow dependency generation with some non-gcc method (e.g., `makedepend`).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `-I`, use `-isystem` to state directories that you don't wish to be output with `-MM`.

This is not mentioned currently at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html despite it seeming to be very closely tied to `-M` and `-MM` options.

Example: this creates correct dependencies of foo.cpp and bar.cpp, *including* Sybase headers:

```
gcc -MM -I/opt/nmr/sap/sybaseASE/sybclient-16.0.3-7/OCS-16_0/include foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

Example: this does the same, but *not including* Sybase headers:

```
gcc -MM -isystem /opt/nmr/sap/sybaseASE/sybclient-16.0.3-7/OCS-16_0/include foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

Here is a sample `Makefile` implementation for `gmake`.  The `patsubst` function is a pattern substitution using % as a part that matches on the "before" that is then captured and used in the "after."  `isystem` appears to need a space after it, but this is easy to generate with `patsubst` as the percent sign keeps the space from being truncated.  The minus option on `-include` tells `gmake` not to complain if the file named doesn't exist.  This allows you to use `gmake` to make `depend` and produce `Make.Dep` even before there *is* a `Make.Dep.`  Finally, this assumes `$(PkgIncDirs)` hold package include directories none of which should be changing, while `$(ProjIncDirs)` would be include directories inside the project that you'd want dependencies to be generated for.

```
depend:
    gcc -MM $(CFlags) $(Defines) $(patsubst -I%, -isystem %, $(PkgIncDirs)) $(ProjIncDirs) $(Source) >Make.Dep

-include Make.Dep
```